# PHP include doesn't work as it should

Tags: php, debian

I have the documents at `http://www.example.com/` in `/home/www/example.com/www` running on Debian Squeeze.

```
/home/www/example.com/
    www/
         index.php
    php/
         include_me.php
```

In the php.ini I've uncommented and changed to:

```
include_path =".:/home/www/example.com"
```

In a script index.php in www, I have `require_once("/php/include_me.php")`. The output I am getting from PHP is:

```
Warning: require_once(/php/include_me.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/www/example.com/www/index.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/php/include_me.php' (include_path='.:/home/www/example.com') in /home/www/example.com/www/index.php on line 2
```

As you can see, the include-path is set correctly according to the error. But if I do `require_once("../php/include_me.php");`, it works. Therefore, something has to be wrong with the include-path.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix it?

Comment: -1 "<insert any function/construct here> doesn't work as it should" is a bad name for your question. Computers do what you tell them to do, not what you want them to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
php/
```

is a relative path and uses the current directory as a starting point

```
./php/
```

is a relative path and explicitly declares the current directory (**.**) as a starting point

```
/php/
```

is a **not** relative path, this means it's starting point is the top level directory (the root directory **/**)

Comment: Exactly. So when using /php/ it should actually include from include_path . /php/

Comment: But it seems like it doesn't.

Comment: No. "/php" will include from a folder at the root of the filing system, which I guess isn't what you want.

Comment: `include_path()` is used to specify search paths for relative includes. So if you have `/var/www/project/libs/:.` in your paths, then including `mylib/hello.php` will check `/var/www/project/libs/mylib/hello.php` as well as the current folder (`./mylib/hello.php`).

Comment: **Relative** paths are composed using the include path, **full** paths are well... full.

Comment: @Student, a relative include will actually use the include_path taking each include path entry in order... typically the current folder is the first entry in that path

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation on [`include`](http://php.net/include):

> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.

Since you're specifying an absolute path in this case, the `include_path` is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Mihai Stancu but I would like to add that it may be better practice to include using dirname(__FILE__) so that as directories get moved around the code won't break.  This will act like an absolute path but allow you to think of them as local paths.

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)` refers to the directory in which the current **file is**, which is different from the directory from which the current **script started** (ex.: index.php includes class/doohickie.php, within the class `dirname(__FILE__) == '/var/www/class'` while `'.' == '/var/www' )`, it depends on what the intended/expected results are

Answer (score 2):

Explanation for require_once("/php/include_me.php"):

You have your include path set for '/home/www/example.com/', but that is a sub-directory of /home/www. Your require_once is looking for /php/include_me.php.

```
/
home/
    www/
        example.com/
              php/
              www/
php/
    include_me.php
```

You have a preceeding / in your require call, which is looking for /php/include_me.php. To look for /home/www/example.com/php/include_me.php you would want:

```
require_once('php/include_me.php');
```

You could also set your include path to:

```
include_path =".:/home/www/example.com/:/home/www/example.com/www/:/home/www/example.com/php/"
```

Answer (score 1):

The beginning slash on your require once will search from the root ... try:

```
require_once('php/include_me.php');
```

Comment: Aha, so if you do use php/include_me.php it will look in the www folder for the file, and if it cannot find it, it will search in include_path . php/include_me.php?

Comment: Both `php/include_me.php` and `./php/include_me.php` should work fine (meaning they should use the include path until they find the file).

Answer (score 1):

This is trying to grab the file literally at /php on your file system, not your web directory.

```
require_once("/php/include_me.php");
```